# IBPP: Get exception in transaction.prepare(...) when using question mark for table name

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I'm using IBPP to use a firebird database in C++. I would like to set the table name in an update sql statement dynamically. So I made the table name an question mark in `Prepare("UPDATE ? ...")` . Unfortunately this raises an error:

> *** IBPP::SQLException *** Context: Statement::Prepare( UPDATE ? SET name = ? WHERE stage_system_id = ? ) Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
>
> SQL Message : -104 Invalid token
>
> Engine Code    : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL
>   error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 8 ?

Is it possible to make the table name a parameter? It is possible by manually create the string - but that's quite cumbersome. Or is making the table name a parameter not a good idear at all?
Below is the full code snippet:

```
try
{
    m_DbStatement->Prepare (
    "UPDATE ? SET name = ? WHERE stage_system_id = ?" /*Works not - throws exception*/
    /*"UPDATE stage_systems SET name = 'qqq' WHERE stage_system_id = 3"*/ /*Works*/
    );
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::string error = e.what();
    throw;
}


m_DbStatement->Set(1, rowElementToUpdate.tableName.c_str ());
m_DbStatement->Set(2, rowElementToUpdate.value.c_str ());
m_DbStatement->Set(3, rowElementToUpdate.primaryKey);

m_DbStatement->Execute ();
m_DbTransaction->CommitRetain ();
}
```

Comment: You need to specify table name in the UPDATE statement, i.e. not a parameter marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parametrize object names (like table names, column names, etc). Query parameters are **only** for values.

This isn't specific to Firebird, or at least: I don't know any database that allows parametrization of object names like this.